# How to make the help text of a content type field collapsible?

Tags: entities, nodes

I have built my Drupal 7 tennisclub-site so that a few users can maintain the content in it.

Most of these few are irregular users, that only come to maintain their part of the content a couple of times a year.
For these people it is important that they are led through the steps of lets say... creating a calendar item, using the field-helptext. So there is a helptext for the title, a helptext for the date(s) and a helptext for the body of the content type "calendar-item".

While very usefull to the infrequent user, these helptexts are quickly becomming annoying to regular users.
How do I make the helptexts collapsible and how do I set it's default state?
Which modules do I need for this to work?

Thanks in advance,

Tijs

Answer (score 1):

Each form element in your input/edit form will be in a div with a unique id, and will have a child division with the 'description' class which contains the help text.

If you know which div's you wish to collapse, it can be done with javascript, following the model for [Collapsible Blocks](http://drupal.org/node/101465).

Comment: collapsible blocks module supports only for blocks what about for the fields?

Comment: Not the module. The code. The javascript is what makes it work. Just follow the model and write your own code. Otherwise you will not be able to make the help text collapsible.